# When I am trying to evaluate a simple MVEL expression getting Error: could not access: name

Tags: java, mvel

```
import org.mvel2.MVEL;

public class MVELEvalTst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "xxx";
        Object eval = MVEL.eval("myName=='xxx'",name);
        System.out.println(eval);
    }

}
```

This is my simple eval expression. When I am running this, getting the below exception. Has anyone ever come across this? Please help.

```
Exception : Exception in thread "main" [Error: could not access: myName; in class: java.lang.String]
[Near : {... myName=='xxx' ....}]
         ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
    at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.getBeanProperty(PropertyAccessor.java:680)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the property `myName` to `MVEL`, so that it can evaluate.

code should be as below

```
import org.mvel2.MVEL;

    public class MVELEvalTst {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String name = "xxx";

            Map map = new HashMap();
            map.put("myName",name);
            Object eval = MVEL.eval("myName=='xxx'",map);
            System.out.println(eval);
        }

    }
```

Now run and check the output. Output is true.
Also do refer the site http://mvel.codehaus.org/

Comment: @BaBaSomanath more for you if you are interested..
http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/06/business-rule-engine-bre-validation.html